Weisfeiler-Leman Algorithm
We know that the Weisfeiler-Leman Algorithm will not always distinguish graphs that are not isomorphic but if two graphs are isomorphic are we guaranteed to get a certificate?

What is a certificate?

I'm actually referring to this section from the Wikipedia article  "If the certificates agree, G and H may or may not be isomorphic."  I'm wondering if the graphs are isomorphic, will the certificates necessarily agree?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weisfeiler_Leman_graph_isomorphism_test

No, because you don't actually get a mapping between graphs (at least not vertex-to-vertex mapping, but you do get a mapping between automorphism groups).
As always with the Weisfeiler Leman graph isomorphism test, you should consider three graphs, all $r$-regular graphs on $n$ vertices, two of which are isomorphic.
Every vertex of every graph will always have the same label.

OK I'm starting to understand.  Thank you.
